# autodetect filesystem on mount()

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mount

My app is supposed to mount and check contents of any pendrive inserted in the USB slot.
The problem is, some users may be using pendrives formatted for other filesystems than standard 'vfat'.
The standard

```
 mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/pendrive -t auto
```

would be sufficient for my needs - it works and any filesystem readable by the kernel will be used.
The problem is I have to do it from within the application, and I'd prefer to avoid calling `system()` and shell commands when "natural" C solution exists.

```
 #include <sys/mount.h>
 ...
 result = mount("/dev/sda1", "/mnt/pendrive", "vfat" ,0, NULL);
```

works correctly. But if I replace `"vfat"` with `"auto"` or `NULL` nothing is mounted.

As I checked sources for busybox's mount, it seems to set the filesystem to NULL in the mount() call if 'auto' or no filesystem type is supplied. But that trick doesn't seem to work for me. What am I missing? Is there some relatively simple way to do this?

Comment: The mount utility is internally trying to detect the file system when you specify the `auto` option as the file system type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel isn't able to auto-detect the file system, so you have to do it yourself.

What busybox actually does is just loop through all the relevant filesystems, parsed from /proc/filesystems, and call mount() until it succeeds (see line [1898](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/mount.c) )

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a loop?

```
#define MAX 4
const char *FSTypes[MAX] = { "ext4", "btrfs", "ntfs", "vfat" };
short Inc = 0;

for (; Inc < MAX; ++Inc)
{
    if (mount("/source", "/target", FSTypes[Inc], 0, NULL) == 0)
    { /*If it's successful, stop.*/
        break;
    }
}
```

I realize it's an old question, but this seems relevant for others searching for answers.

Answer (score 1):

If `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/pendrive -t auto` is what you need to do. Then just do that.

```
sprintf(cmd, "mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/pendrive -t auto")    
rc = system(cmd);
```

or

```
sprintf(cmd, "mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/pendrive -t auto")    
if ((p = popen(cmd, "w")) != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

Should work fine. You may need to listen to udev events or scan the udev log for currently connected USB mass storage devices in order to get the node path, but that should get you started.

Comment: The one that put the question asked explicitly that he would prefer to don't need to use ```system()``` nor open a shell...